# Accessing Page URL from within Partial View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a page which has a partial view included within a div called test. I may request more content to be placed within this div by receiving back a PartialViewResult.

I want to be able to obtain the url of the page (i.e. what is shown in the address bar) from within the PartialView code but when I use Request.Url, it gives me the URL of the PartialView only.

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all?

Comment: IMO a view should not have access to its URl, it would be against the separation between View and Controller, isn't it?

Comment: yeah, normally I'd be able to just do Request.Url to find it, but since it's in a PartialView, this might not be possible

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured out another way of doing it - now using the HTTP_REFERER Request.ServerVariable to work out what page requested it. Not a disaster if the HTTP_REFERER isn't populated, have got a fallback for that